# get list of unused numbers from an unsorted array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to get the smallest unused number from an unsorted array. I could not sort the array because this is just a test program, in the actual program, I would be taking values from an array of objects.

So while trying to get the smallest unused number, I managed to get the list of unused numbers. It was perfect for the first random numbers I wrote in the program, but the second time, output was wrong.

This is the code I tried

```
class smallestUnusedNumberTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] testArray = {1, 5, 7, 11, 4, 8};
        int largest = 1;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
            if(testArray[i] > largest) {
                largest = testArray[i];
            }
        }
        for(i = 1; i < largest; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < testArray.length; j++) {
                if(i == testArray[j]) {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

and the output i get is

```
2
3
5
6
9
10
```

I get 5, which is already there in the array.
I have used a `for` loop to get the largest number from the array. But then, I am not able to figure out the correct logic.

What should I do to get the correct unused numbers from the array? I need the output in an ascending order.

Comment: Why don't you make your objects implement the Comparable interface and sort them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the logic of your algorithm: you increment `i` inside the inner loop when you find a match, but you continue with the loop. Therefore, when you find a `4` after `5`, you increment `i` from `4` to `5`, but you never go back to the beginning of the array to see if some of the earlier elements are `5`.

To fix this, define a `boolean` variable inside the outer loop, set it to `false` initially, and then set it to `true` in the inner loop when you find `i == testArray[j]`; break out of the loop when you find a match.

Check your boolean variable after the inner loop. If it is `true`, the number is there, so you should not print anything. Otherwise, print the number.

Comment: yes... that's what I was missing. I added j = 0 below i++, and now it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag to know if the value is unused.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] testArray = {1, 5, 7, 11, 4, 8};
        int largest = 1;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
            if(testArray[i] > largest) {
                largest = testArray[i];
            }
        }
        for(i = 1; i < largest; i++) {
            boolean unused = true;
            for(int j = 0; j < testArray.length; j++) {
                if(i == testArray[j]) {
                    unused = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (unused)
                System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly a learning exercise. Writing the code for OP does not help him or her learn, even when *your* code is 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps...

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class SmallestUnused {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] testArray = {1, 5, 7, 11, 4, 8};
    Arrays.sort(testArray);
    int smallest = testArray[0];
    int largest = testArray[testArray.length-1];
    int smallestUnused = largest + 1;
    System.out.println("smallest: "+smallest);
    System.out.println("largest: "+largest);
    if(smallest>1){
        smallestUnused = 1;
    }else{
        for(int i=2; i<largest; i++){
            if(Arrays.binarySearch(testArray, i)<0){
                smallestUnused = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Smallest unused: "+smallestUnused);
}

}
```

Comment: I have assumed that we're interested only in natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a sub-method this will make your life much easier

```
//returns true if the array parameter contains num, false if not
private boolean contains(int num, int[] array) {
  // fill this in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the loops by simplifying your code like this -

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] testArray = {1, 5, 7, 11, 4, 8};
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            i++;
            boolean small = false;
            boolean unused = true;
            for (int j : testArray) {
                if (i == j) {
                    unused = false;
                    break;
                } else if (i < j) {
                    small = true;
                }
            }
            if (small && unused) {
                System.out.println(i);
            } else if (!small && unused) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in four steps without any nested loops.

1. Find the largest value in testArray. You already have code for that.
2. Create a new array of booleans, size largest+1, with all values initialized to false. Let's call this usedValues[].
3. Loop through testArray again. For each element of testArray, set usedValues[testArray[i]] = true.
4. Finally, loop through usedValues[]. The index for the first element where usedValues[i] == false is your lowest unused value from testArray.

And given that you say you want to print all the unused numbers in ascending order, you can do that with one pass through the usedValues array, simply printing the indexes of all elements where usedValues[i] == false.